# How to load query string arguments in Flask Marshmallow schema

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow

I have a POST request defined in my Flask app as below:

```
https://www.foo.com/<foo_id>?bar_id=3
```

I am getting the **path parameter** `foo_id` as below:

```
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource

ns = Namespace('Foo API')

@ns.route("/<string:foo_id>")
class FooExecute(Resource):

    def get(self, foo_id):
        print('foo_id = {}'.format(foo_id))
```

Though I am not able to get the **query paramater** `bar_id`. What is the right way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [Request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request) class within Flask to get the params as follows:

```py
from flask import request

request.args.get('bar_id')
```

Answer (score -3):

Am using **requests** approach which is the best.

see documentation
[link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

First, You will need to Install and import requests via

```
pip install requests
```

here is a sample code that will work for you.
just replace `<foo_id>` with your main value

```
import requests
import json

item = { "bar_id": "3"}
resp1 = requests.post("https://www.foo.com.com/<foo_id>/?", data=item))

print('data sent successfully')
print (resp1.status_code)


content = json.loads(resp1.content)
print(content)
```